# Conditionally load ng-animate module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

We are using the Angular 1.4.9 ng-animate module.  Everything works fine, but some of our teams are asking to a way to NOT load in based on a condition.

For example, on a particular platform or user agent, no ng-animate loads.

We already have a few ways to test for this (e.g.modernizr) and use these to conditionally load other .js and .css files, but since ng-animate is a module simply excluding its js file would throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bootstrap your application manually it's actually pretty simple.

Keep your dependencies in a global variable:

```
window.myApplicationMeta = {
  dependencies: [j]
};
```

Use this when you define your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', applicationMeta.dependencies)
```

Modify the dependencies before you bootstrap the application:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {

  var condition = true;

  if (condition) applicationMeta.dependencies.push('ngAnimate');

  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); 
});
```